Imperfect coding theory problem: Locating $j$ and determining the best constant $k_{q}$

Let $\mathbf{x}= \left ( x_{1}, x_{2}, \ldots, x_{n} \right )\in\left\{ 0, 1, \ldots, q- 1 \right\}^{n}$ be unknown, but its syndrome is given:
$$\operatorname{Syn}\left ( \mathbf{x} \right )= \sum\limits_{i= 1}^{n}\binom{i+ 1}{2}x_{i}\mod k_{q}qn$$
where $k_{q}$ is a positive constant independent of $n$, but dependent on $q$.
Let $\mathbf{y}= \left ( y_{1}, y_{2}, \ldots, y_{n- 1} \right )\in\left\{ 0, 1, \ldots, q- 1 \right\}^{n- 1}$ be defined as:
$$y_{i}= \left\{\begin{matrix} x_{i}, & 1\leq i< j, \\ x_{j}+ x_{j+ 1}, & i= j, \\ x_{i+ 1}, & j< i\leq n- 1 \\ \end{matrix}\right.$$
for some unknown $j\in\left\{ 1, 2, \ldots, n- 1 \right\}$.
Additional parameters: $a= x_{j}, b= x_{j+ 1}$

INPUT: $q, n, \operatorname{Syn}\left ( \mathbf{x} \right ), \mathbf{y}$ (according to the chosen $j$), $a= x_{j}, b= x_{j+ 1}$
OUTPUT: Locate $j$, and optimize the constant $k_{q}$, ensuring it allows precise recovery of $j$ for any valid input (If $k_{q}$ is a constant, that’s already great, but the smaller it is, the more it proves that using syndrome differences is effective in locating $i$ with the fewest possible equations/inequalities as following.)
My approach: Using sub-syndromes $\operatorname{Syn}_{+}\left ( \mathbf{y} \right )= \sum\limits_{i= 2}^{n}\binom{i+ 1}{2}y_{i}, \operatorname{Syn}_{-}\left ( \mathbf{y} \right )= \sum\limits_{i= 1}^{n- 1}\binom{i+ 1}{2}y_{i}$, we obtain:
$\operatorname{Syn}_{+}\left ( \mathbf{y} \right )- \operatorname{Syn}\left ( \mathbf{x} \right )= \sum\limits_{i= 1}^{j}\left ( i+ 1 \right )y_{i}- \left ( j+ 1 \right )b= \sum\limits_{i= 1}^{j}iy_{i}+ \left ( j+ 1 \right )a\mod k_{q}qn$, furthurmore:
$\operatorname{Syn}\left ( \mathbf{y} \right )- \operatorname{Syn}_{-}\left ( \mathbf{x} \right )= \sum\limits_{i= j}^{n}iy_{i}\mod k_{q}qn$.
But unfortunately, at the moment, I’m not using a linear search strategy or anything similar useful. I need your help to overcome modulus of $k_{q}qn$ for these 2 syndrome differences. Thanks a real lot!

Still unclear (at least to me, and I was an associate editor of coding theory for IEEE at one point). I'm sure there is an interesting application underlying this, but it is too messy for my taste (when the modulus varies inside the problem). Also, exactly what do you mean by optimizing the constant $k_q$? You may need to describe the application for this to make sense. A link, may be? Of course, if Mike now understands it, then it's probably ok. I feel a bit grumpy, and bicker about the fact that unless $k_qqn$ is a prime number, you have exited the world of finite fields :-(

Better to describe it here. Not sure when I will have the time to take a look at it.

@JyrkiLahtonen If you are interested in 1-deletion codes, you might know that in 2023, Nguyen Tuan Thanh et al. developed non-binary optimal redundancy codes for correcting 1-deletion. However, Nguyen Tuan Thanh used Differential VT codes, which rely on a syndrome. When converted from non-systematic to systematic, the syndrome takes the form of $\sum x_{i}$, which I should called Uniform codes' syndrome, which completely fails to locate the substitution error position. My code construction is based on Differential Triangular codes, and I have successfully used it to solve 1-substitution codes.

@JyrkiLahtonen The problem I am addressing is the final stage to solve 1-deletion codes. About the Differential forms of codes: Triangular codes (1-sub) > DiffTriangular codes (1-del?/1-sub) ≈ VT codes (1-sub) > DiffVT codes (1-del) ≈ Uniform codes (0-edit).

@JyrkiLahtonen To explain $k_{q}$, I can only say that as long as $k_{q}$ is a constant, its specific value doesn’t matter. However, the lower $k_{q}$​ is, the more efficient I understand the handling of syndrome differences becomes. This helps reduce the problem into a system of equations/inequalities with two variables to locate $i$, for example. Since the formalization of my problem is $y_{i}= x_{i}+ x_{i+ 1}$, predicting $k_{q}= 2$ might be overly optimistic.

I'm afraid I'm not familiar with those even though the construction did remind me of Klöve's code designed to detect a deletion of a symbol. And, looking at it, I don't understand your definition of $Syn(x)$. The variables $x_i$ are elements of $\Bbb{Z}_q$, so only known modulo $q$. Therefore all the terms $\binom{i+1}2 x_i$ are similarly only well-defined as elements of $\Bbb{Z}_q$.

@JyrkiLahtonen Thank you for letting me know about Klöve codes that detect 1-deletion. The problem I’m solving focuses on correcting worst-case 1-deletion (asymmetric synchronization error). As for $\mathbb{Z}q$, it still needs to be used because this non-binary problem has applications in DNA-based storage, where the decoding method requires Differential techniques. Thus, the code construction must use $x{i}\in\mathbb{Z}_q$, which also helps optimize information.

There is nothing for you to apologize for per se kangwon_1502m but realize that it is on the OP to right their questions fairly. In any event learning how to motivate and explain your questions on MSE is a skill that transfers well, here and in your career in maths in general.
